# What format does System.Data.SqlClient use to transmit procedure parameters to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, sqlclient

Trying to estimate the amount of data transmitted over a network to SQL server when using System.Data.SqlClient to execute procedures with SqlDbType.Structured parameters. Assuming a non-encrypted connection, would the following provide a reasonable estimate?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//Fill with data
using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize(ms, dt);
   var dataSize = ms.Length;
 }
```

Comment: what does a data table have to do with procedure parameters?

Comment: The type used when executing a stored procedure with a SqlDbType.Structured parameter.

Comment: I see, you are passing a table as a parameter.  The network bandwidth will be related to the size of the table -- how could this possibly matter?  Are you going to passs a 1 mb table? -- most networks would not care -- a 1 gb table?  Why would you ever need to do that?

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason to think a binary formatter  in C# would have anything to do with the transit format of the SQL Client.

The best way to estimate (not quite clear what you want to estimate) is documentation if it exists or just a network monitor and some test cases.

> This question concerns me -- I can't think of a use case where this would be an issue.  Any reasonable size table (eg 1 mb) would be fast on all current networks.  Any big table (eg 1gb) is a signal you have a bad design.  If the issue is a constrained system (eg IOT) you probably want a better design.